OS on instances
Already Tried - As per documentation Garden will act as container which run on "Diego" cell.
And droplet will have 1. Stack - OS on which app runs 2. Build Pack- Source Code and libraries.
Does every instance spin in Garden will have its own OS because of stack? Or all instances will share OS on VM on which Diego Cell is hosted?
